# Which Custom Geographic Transformation Method to use for Nad83 to Nad 83 (CSRS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, canada, nad83

I couldn't find a NTv2 file for transforming GCS NAD83 to GCS NAD83(CSRS) so I'm trying to create a custom transformation using the 'Create Custom Geographic Transformation' tool in ArcMap. The tool seems pretty straightforward but I don't know what transformation method I should use.

I'm using ArcMap 10.3 and am working in UTM zone 11N (in BC) if that is useful at all.

Comment: Is the data in Alberta or British Columbia? Generally, you need to contact the provincial geodetic agency to get NTv2 grids.

Comment: It's in BC. Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: BC has published a bunch. Look for their [MASCOT utilities](http://a100.gov.bc.ca/pub/mascotw/protected/survey.html). Once you agree to their terms, you can download the gsb files.

Comment: Update: I got in contact with GeoBC and they did have the NTv2 file I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to turn that into an answer!

Comment: I think I am having similar problem. I downloaded the ATSv4.1 grid from Altalis.ca (sections and quarter section line work) and they tell me that it is in Geographic/NAD83 coordinate system. When I select EPSG:4269, all my line work appears stretched in the E-W direction (all sections are rectangular, rather than squares). Why is that? What GCS should I be using? If anybody could recommend the right EPSG ID number that would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: also see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304398/nad-1983-to-nad-1983-csrs-transformation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I got in contact with GeoBC and they did have the NTv2 file I was looking for. Thank you!